# Why Laravel Auth::guard()->attempt() isn't working?

Tags: php, laravel

So basically I generate users data after a payment, which it is saved in a table I created, it has a username and a encrypted password with Hash::make() method.

What I wanna do is to login with that data stored in the DB, so I made a guard.

This is the `auth.php` file with guards:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'plataforma' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'usuario',
    ],
],
```

And these are the providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'usuario' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
    ],
```

This is the model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'plataforma';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre_usuario', 'correo', 'clave',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'clave', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And finally the controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class PlataformaController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('web.plataforma-login');
    }

    public function autenticar(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('plataforma')->attempt(['nombre_usuario' => $request->input('nombre_usuario'), 'clave' => $request->input('clave')])) {
            return view('web.plataforma');
        } else {
            dd(Auth::guard('plataforma')->attempt(['nombre_usuario' => $request->input('nombre_usuario'), 'clave' => $request->input('clave')]));
        }
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('web.plataforma');
    }
}
```

So basically the Auth::guard('plataforma')->attempt(...) returns false, I already checked that the values of $request->input(...) are correct, I checked that the encrypted password in the DB is the same as the password that the user enter with Hash::check(), so I don't know what is wrong and I'm so confused...

I spent a lot of time reading other questions with no solutions either, I would be glad if anyone can help me out.

Comment: you means you wants to do auto login using credentials getting from db?

Comment: I think it has to do with the key names you've chosen. `password` seems to be hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the API, I've come to the conclusion `attempt()` is not working to you because you're using a different password column name.

The following is the `attempt` function's code from the `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class:

> ```
> /**
>  * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
>  *
>  * @param  array  $credentials
>  * @param  bool  $remember
>  * @return bool
>  */
> public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
> {
>     $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember);
>
>     $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
>
>     // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
>     // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
>     // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
>     if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
>         $this->login($user, $remember);
>
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
>     // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
>     // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
>     $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```

The key functions here are `retrieveByCredentials` and `hasValidCredentials`

Here's `retrieveByCredentials` from `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`. As you can see, it's excluding the `'password'` key from the query in the foreach.

> ```
> /**
>  * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
>  *
>  * @param  array  $credentials
>  * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
>  */
> public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
> {
>     if (empty($credentials) ||
>        (count($credentials) === 1 &&
>         → Str::contains($this->firstCredentialKey($credentials), 'password'))) { ←
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
>     // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
>     // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
>     $query = $this->newModelQuery();
>
>     foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
>         → if (Str::contains($key, 'password')) { ←
>             continue;
>         }
>
>         if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
>             $query->whereIn($key, $value);
>         } elseif ($value instanceof Closure) {
>             $value($query);
>         } else {
>             $query->where($key, $value);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return $query->first();
> }
> ```

---

Here's `hasValidCredentials` from `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`. The key function here is `validateCredentials`

> ```
> /**
>  * Determine if the user matches the credentials.
>  *
>  * @param  mixed  $user
>  * @param  array  $credentials
>  * @return bool
>  */
> protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
> {
>     $validated = ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
>
>     if ($validated) {
>         $this->fireValidatedEvent($user);
>     }
>
>     return $validated;
> }
> ```

---

Here's `validateCredentials` from the `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` class. You can see it's again, using by default `'password'` as the key name. Let's see what `getAuthPassword()` looks like.

> ```
> /**
>  * Validate a user against the given credentials.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
>  * @param  array  $credentials
>  * @return bool
>  */
> public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
> {
>     → $plain = $credentials['password']; ←
>
>     return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
> }
> ```

---

And finally `getAuthPassword` from the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` class. It's just returning the model's `'password'` attribute.

> ```
> /**
>  * Get the password for the user.
>  *
>  * @return string
>  */
> public function getAuthPassword()
> {
>     → return $this->password; ←
> }
> ```

---

---

---

Basically, if you want this to work, you need to change a few things about your code.

1. Use `password` as the key in `attempt()`

```php
public function autenticar(Request $request)
{
    $attempt = Auth::guard('plataforma')->attempt([
        'nombre_usuario' => $request->input('nombre_usuario'),
        'password' => $request->input('clave')
    ]);

    if ($attempt) {
        return view('web.plataforma');
    } else {
        dd($attempt);
    }
}
```

2. Override your Authenticatable model (Usuario)'s `getAuthPassword` method.

```php
# Usuario model
/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->clave;
}
```

Comment: thanks, how i can change username field name to other field  same like password ?

Comment: You can use whatever username field you want as far as I remember. Password is the only field that needs some extra work. `Auth::attempt(['your-custom-username-field' => ..., 'password' => ...])`